# How to restart an SWF with a click of a button?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a drag and drop mini-game and, once finished, I wish for the user to be able to click a "try again" button and have the whole thing start over.
I have read in to this and see that there are a couple of options but am stuck as to which would be best for me.
I have created an FLA with all of my library items, an AS file (*MainGame.as*) with the main game and all of it's functions in one class and a second AS file (*MyGame.as*) which calls the class file to play the game.

Which would work best for me?
I have nothing on the layers and just cannot figure out how to remove the swf and load it again with the click of a button.
Am I right in thinking that I would add the button to the *MyGame* file in the `timerDone` function?
If so, how would I use that to reload the SWF from the start?

Here is my `timerDone` function ...

```
function timerDone(e:TimerEvent=null):void
            {                           
                if (countDown == 0)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    finalScore = score;
                }
                else
                {                   
                    count = (30) - (myTimer.currentCount);
                    finalScore = (count * 10) + (score);

                }
                myText.text = "GAME OVER!";
                myText.x = 195;
                displayText();                          
                myText2.text = "Your score = " + (finalScore);
                displayText2();
            }
```

I am thinking that I add the button after the last line and somehow refresh the SWF, is that right?
Or am I way off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like that: you call the function toReplay at the end of your function timerDone:

**Function timerDone, after "displayText2();"**

```
tryAgain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toReplay);
```

**Outside the function timerDone**

```
/**
 * The function toReplay calls the function init which 
 * initializes the Timer and all your variables.
 **/
function toReplay(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toReplay);
    init();
}

function init():void {
    // Timer
    count = 0;
    finalScore = 0;
    myText.text = "";
    // etc.
}
```

And the function init can directly be invoked to initialize all your variables at the begining of the game:

```
init();
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened.
Well, the tryagain button appeared but otherwise it had no effect.
I've fiddled about with it but am none the wiser.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ZombieDude What your function init must contain depends on your code.

Comment: Sorry to sound dense but, what do you mean?
Also, I wrote the code to suit my program, but it failed.
The button wasn't even clickable. I know I am missing something, just not sure what!

Comment: @ZombieDude If you put the code like I indicate you : invocation of the function toReplay at the end of the function timerDone, it signifies that the action will occur when the function timerDone will play. To see if your function init plays, you can write `trace("it plays");` at the end of your function timerDone, in your function toReplay or in your function init.

Comment: Yeah, trace function works. But for some reason none of the event listeners get removed.
Weird!